# AJAX won't load request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working on date filters for a line chart with `Chart JS` and after modifying, including the values of the date ranges, the chart won't work. I don't get any errors logged in the console.

There are 3 PHP files in use: one to store and manage a connection with SAP, a second one to handle the ajax call and the homepage with the chart in question.

It has the following structure:

script inside index.php - the ajax call that doesn't work

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selector-ceco').on('change', function(){

            // -------------variables actualizacion graficas -----------
            //console.log($('#fecha_i').val(), typeof $('#fecha_i').val());
            var ceco = String($('#selector-ceco').val());
            var fecha_i = $('#fecha_i').val().replace(/-/g, '');
            var fecha_f = $('#fecha_f').val().replace(/-/g, '');
            //if (ceco==0) {ceco="";};
            console.log(typeof fecha_f, fecha_f);

            var montos = []; var fechas = []; var gasto_total = 0; var dates =[];
            
            $.ajax({
                url: "inc/cargar_hist_cecos.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'ceco_electo':ceco, 'fecha_i': fecha_i, 'fecha_f': fecha_f},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(retorno, status){
                    console.log("llegue");
                    for (let i = 0 ; i<retorno.length ; i++){
                        montos.push(parseFloat(retorno[i]['TOTAL']));
                        fechas.push(retorno[i]['FECHA'].replace(/(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)/,'$1-$2'));
                        //dates.push(Date(retorno[i]['FECHA']));
                        gasto_total += parseFloat(retorno[i]['TOTAL']);
                    };
                    
                    //console.log(typeof dates[0], Date(fechas[0]));
                    

                    gasto_ceco.data.datasets[0].data = montos;
                    gasto_ceco.data.labels = fechas;
                    gasto_ceco.update();
                }
            });
```

the AJAX call handler

```
<?php
include_once 'db.inc.php';

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['ceco_electo'])){
    $CONN_data = new DbS;
    
    $valores = $CONN_data->gasto_ceco( $_POST['ceco_electo'] , $_SESSION['grupo'], $_POST['fecha_i'], $_POST['fecha_f']);

    $hist = json_encode($valores);
    echo $hist;
}else{
    echo "error";
};  

?>
```

the connection file:

```
public function gasto_ceco ($CECO, $tipo, $fecha_i, $fecha_f){
            $pdo = $this->connect_sap();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql = <<<SQL
                    SELECT T2."OcrCode" as "CECO", sum(T2."Quantity"*T2."Price") as "TOTAL", YEAR(T4."DocDate")*100+MONTH(T4."DocDate") as FECHA
                    FROM PCH1 T2 INNER JOIN OPCH T4 on T4."DocEntry"=T2."DocEntry"
                    WHERE T2."AcctCode" like '55%' AND T4."DocDate" > '20220101' AND T4."CANCELED" <> 'N ' AND T2."OcrCode" = {$CECO} AND T4."DocDate" > cast({$fecha_i} as VARCHAR) AND T4."DocDate" < CAST({$fecha_f} as VARCHAR)
                    GROUP BY T2."OcrCode", YEAR(T4."DocDate")*100+MONTH(T4."DocDate")
                    ORDER BY YEAR(T4."DocDate")*100+MONTH(T4."DocDate") ASC 
            SQL;
            
            
            echo $sql;
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            
            $res = $stmt->execute();
            
            echo $res;
            
            try {
                return $gasto_ceco = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "error: ".$e->getMessage();
            };
            

        }



    };
```

I tried creating another file that calls the functions and the query works, I tried getting the AJAX error message, but it led me nowhere.

Previously I had the same function, but without `fecha_i` and `fecha_f` and the modifications to the query, and files that it implies and it worked just fine.

EDIT:
if it helps somehow here is the HTML for this chart:

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <div class="chart-area">
                        <input type="date" id="fecha_i" value="2022-01-01" name="fecha_i">
                        <input type="date" id="fecha_f" value="2023-12-31" name="fecha_f">
                        <canvas id="grafico-gasto-ceco"></canvas>
                        
                        <script>
                            var labels= []; var data_gasto_raw = [];
                            var ctx_gasto_ceco = document.getElementById("grafico-gasto-ceco").getContext('2d');
                            var config = {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: labels,
                                    datasets: [{
                                        data: data_gasto_raw,
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(78, 115, 223, 0.05)',
                                        lineTension: 0.3,
                                        pointRadius: 3,
                                        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                                        pointHoverRadius: 3,
                                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                                        pointBorderWidth: 2,
                                        
                                    }],
                                options: {responsive:true,
                                         layout: {
                                              padding: {
                                                left: 10,
                                                right: 25,
                                                top: 25,
                                                bottom: 20
                                              }
                                            },
                                          scales: {
                                              xAxes: [{
                                                time: {
                                                  unit: 'date'
                                                },
                                                gridLines: {
                                                  display: false,
                                                  drawBorder: false
                                                },
                                                ticks: {
                                                  maxTicksLimit: 7
                                                }
                                              }],
                                              yAxes: [{
                                                ticks: {
                                                  maxTicksLimit: 5,
                                                  padding: 10,
                                                  // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                                                  callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                                    return '$' + number_format(value);
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                gridLines: {
                                                  color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                                                  zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                                                  drawBorder: false,
                                                  borderDash: [2],
                                                  zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
                                                }
                                              }],
                                            },
                                            legend: {display: false},
                                            tooltips: {
                                                  backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
                                                  bodyFontColor: "#858796",
                                                  titleMarginBottom: 10,
                                                  titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
                                                  titleFontSize: 14,
                                                  borderColor: '#dddfeb',
                                                  borderWidth: 1,
                                                  xPadding: 15,
                                                  yPadding: 15,
                                                  displayColors: false,
                                                  intersect: false,
                                                  mode: 'index',
                                                  caretPadding: 10
                                                }
                                         }
                                }
                            };
                            var gasto_ceco = new Chart(ctx_gasto_ceco, config);
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Try deleting `echo $res;`

Comment: sorry, i put that there to check if the query executed at all, but deleting it did nothing.

Comment: Is your request sent at all? If you open your browser's Dev Tools and after that send the request, do you see the request in the Networks tab? If so, what do you see in the Response subtab?

Comment: thank you, seeing the response tab helped me solve it, it was returning the query attached to the json data. (i know huge red fleg, but im just llearning this.

Comment: Happy to help! I have provided an answer accordingly that provides general suggestions of how you can gather information of similar problems in order to solve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to troubleshoot problems, one needs to gather information about the error. In the case of the client-side of your web page you can check the Console tab of your Dev Tools to see whether a JS error happened and you can also check the Network tab in order to see whether a request is sent at all. There you can check what headers are sent to the server, what request type is being used and what parameters are being passed as well as the response of the server. If there is an internal server error, you can check whether the request is well-formed and whether it's valid to expect a normal response. If so, then you need to consult the error logs of your server to see what happened and debug your server-side functionalities. Otherwise, you need to make sure that the request is well-formed.

In our case it turned out that the request was well-formed and the server correctly processed it and even sent a response, but the client-side received a response it did not expect because the SQL query ended up being part of the response due to the line of

```
echo $sql;
```

As clarified in the comment-section, it turned out that narrowing down the problem-space in the way I described at the start of this answer helped you finding your error. Moral of the story: if you face an issue in the future, you will need to try and narrow down the problem-space, seeing whether your request is well-formed, whether your server handles proper requests properly and whether the response of the server is compatible with the expectations of your client-side.